# Why are my pencil/brush paths invisible in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

When using the brush or pencil in Illustrator I would always see the path (basically a blue outline). For some reason I never see it anymore. I have to wait until my shape or object is finished before I can see what it looks like on the screen. Any help would be great.

Comment: Can you please attach a screenshot on what it looks like "When it's finished" and you *can* see it.

Comment: Can you tell us which version of Illustrator you are using? Have you tried to go to View > Show Edges?

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured it out on my own. Went to preferences and then guides & grid. Changed from lines to dots. Restarted illustrator. Seems to have worked now.